# How can i get each string elements of array by a string in Standart C?

Tags: arrays, string, char, printf

```
char *cmd={
'9436',
'1,1,1331,0700',
'1,1,2030,2100',
'1,3,1230,1300',
'1,4,1230,1300',
'2,1,1230,1300',
'2,2,0830,0900',
'2,3,1230,1300',
'2,4,1230,1300',
'3,5,0530,0600',
'4,5,0530,0600'
};
```

i want to print each  elements by string like '9436', '1,1,1331,0700', ...
but it doeasnt work.

my wrong code is :

```
int main(){
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf( "%s", (string))cmd[i] );
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Use double quotes quotes `"9436"`; single quotes are for `char`, _And do not secretly read javascript._  Remove the string cast.

Comment: thank you.i replaced the ' sign with " it worked. So, ho can i convert each string elements to array? For example : '1,1,1331,0700' must be an array ->  { 1,1,1331,0700 } ?    Thanks for help.